# PHP: Recursive copy

Tags: php, recursion, copy, directory

I'm using this code to recursive copy of directories (and files). I can't understand why but, after a copy, my $source folder increase ... it has 76.3MB, after a copy it will increase to 123 MB! Any ideia?

```
<?php

class MyDirectory {

    public function copy($source, $destination, $directoryPermission = 0755, $filePermission = 0644) {
        $source = $this->addSlash($source);
        $destination = $this->addSlash($destination);
        $directoryIterator = new DirectoryIterator($source);

        if (!file_exists($destination)) {
            mkdir($destination, $directoryPermission);
        }

        foreach ($directoryIterator as $fileInfo) {
            $filePath = $fileInfo->getPathname();
            $newDestination = str_replace($source, $destination, $filePath);

            if (!$fileInfo->isDot()) {
                if ($fileInfo->isFile()) {
                    copy($filePath, $newDestination);
                    chmod($newDestination, $filePermission);
                } else if ($fileInfo->isDir()) {
                    mkdir($newDestination, $directoryPermission);
                    $this->copy($filePath, $newDestination);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private function addSlash($directory) {
        if (!empty($directory)) {
            if (!preg_match('/\/$/', $directory)) {
                $directory .= '/';
            }

            return $directory;
        }
    }

}
```

UPDATE: There is no significance differences to increase the source size!

```
$ diff -rq mag/ copy-mag/
Only in mag//app/etc: local.xml
```

Thank you.

Comment: no offense but: It's destination, not destiny : )

Comment: I would want to add that it's a bad idea to create to deduce the destination directory with str_replace. If a part of the path repeats, you're screwed.

Comment: Evert, any alternative to that? Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware there is a RecursiveDirectorIterator as well?

Answer (score 0):

It's very tough to deduce from the source code what goes wrong.

Analyze the directory instead, compare the differences, and update your question with the results. You can use a tool like [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php) (commercial but 30-day trial available) to find out what went wrong.